# Clojure: using ragtime with sqlite3

Tags: jdbc, clojure, sqlite

I'd like to use [ragtime](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime) to manage migrations on an SQLite database. Following the [instructions here](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime/wiki/Getting-Started), i've tried the following in the REPL:

```
(require '[ragtime.jdbc :as jdbc]
         '[ragtime.repl :as repl])

(def config
     {:datastore  (jdbc/sql-database {:connection-uri "jdbc:sqlite:resources/db.sqlite3"})
      :migrations (jdbc/load-resources "migrations")})

(repl/migrate config)
```

All I get is the following error:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named  clojure.core/name (core.clj:1546)
```

The database file exists in `resources/db.sqlite3`. I've tried tracing the exception (i can add the stack trace if needed), but it seems to happen deep in `clojure.java.jdbc`.

As I'm new to the JVM and JDBC, I'm also not sure whether I'm specifying the `:connection-uri` correctly; I've tried several variants but can't seem to make it worK.

Any help would be much appreciated !

---

EDIT: stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named
 at clojure.core$name.invokeStatic (core.clj:1546)
    clojure.core$name.invoke (core.clj:1540)
    clojure.java.jdbc$as_sql_name.invokeStatic (jdbc.clj:67)
    clojure.java.jdbc$as_sql_name.invoke (jdbc.clj:56)
    clojure.java.jdbc$create_table_ddl$spec_to_string__2511.invoke (jdbc.clj:1052)
    clojure.core$map$fn__4785.invoke (core.clj:2646)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:40)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.first (LazySeq.java:71)
    clojure.lang.RT.first (RT.java:667)
    clojure.core$first__4339.invokeStatic (core.clj:55)
    clojure.string$join.invokeStatic (string.clj:180)
    clojure.string$join.invoke (string.clj:180)
    clojure.java.jdbc$create_table_ddl.invokeStatic (jdbc.clj:1056)
    clojure.java.jdbc$create_table_ddl.doInvoke (jdbc.clj:1041)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:423)
    ragtime.jdbc$migrations_table_ddl.invokeStatic (jdbc.clj:16)
    ragtime.jdbc$migrations_table_ddl.invoke (jdbc.clj:15)
    ragtime.jdbc$ensure_migrations_table_exists.invokeStatic (jdbc.clj:22)
    ragtime.jdbc$ensure_migrations_table_exists.invoke (jdbc.clj:20)
    ragtime.jdbc.SqlDatabase.applied_migration_ids (jdbc.clj:42)
    ragtime.core$migrate_all.invokeStatic (core.clj:43)
    ragtime.core$migrate_all.invoke (core.clj:32)
    ragtime.repl$migrate.invokeStatic (repl.clj:49)
    ragtime.repl$migrate.invoke (repl.clj:34)
    thulium.core$eval8407.invokeStatic (form-init2686611279014890656.clj:1)
    (the rest is REPL and compiler calls)
```

And the two migration files, `resources/migrations/001-initial.up.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE tests (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);
```

and `resources/migrations/001-initial.down.sql`:

```
DROP TABLE tests;
```

Comment: The full stack trace would likely be helpful in tracking this down.  Also, you may need an absolute path to the sqlite db.

Comment: I would also recommend posting the contents of your migration files.

Comment: Giving an absolute path for the DB gives the exact same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a go with these versions:

```
[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.6.1"]
[org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.8.7"]
```